# android concat string OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, string, stringbuffer

I'm using a http request lib to fetch xml content. The listener of the lib has the following functions:

```
void onDataReceived(char[] data)
{

}

void onRequestSucceeded()
{

}
```

After requesting a url, the lib will receive the data in many pieces, when every piece of data is received, the `onDataReceived` function will be called, and this piece of data will be passed in as parameter, and I have to concat all the pieces into one string. And after the request is finished, the `onRequestSucceeded` function will be called and the string is now the full content of the xml.

I'm doing it like this:

```
//init the result string
String resStr = new String("");

void onDataReceived(char[] data)
{
    resStr += new String(data);
}

void onRequestSucceeded()
{
    //now the resStr is ready for parse.
}
```

The problem is, sometimes my android device report OutOfMemoryError when concating the String. So I changed to StringBuffer like this:

```
//init the result string
StringBuffer resStr = new StringBuffer("");

void onDataReceived(char[] data)
{
    resStr.append(data);
}

void onRequestSucceeded()
{
    //now the resStr is ready for parse.
}
```

But resStr.toString() gives me weird content like "@bsdawevas". I suspect there's something wrong about the encoding, But I don't know how to solve it.

Any ideas?

Comment: try to write smth like this: resStr.append(new String(data))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try  `resStr.append(new String(data));`

Comment: I don't know why you get down voted, but you solved my problem. But I doubt if this will cause OutOfMemoryError too.

Comment: I'm testing if this can cause OutOfMemoryError now.

Comment: string concatenation is very memory inefficient in most scenarios rather use `StringBuilder` or `String.format`. With the `StringBuilder` you shouldn't have memory problems

Comment: @Wood did that sort out your `OutOfMemoryError`?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
String str = resStr.toString();
System.out.println(str);
```

toString() will convert from StringBuffer to String object